# make fails when trying to compile libmtp

Tags: makefile, ld

I have tried to install a newer version of libmtp on my kubuntu.
But I did not succeed with these versions: 1.1.12, 1.1.13, 1.1.14.
I have downloaded the sources from here:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/libmtp/files/libmtp/

Then:
- unpack
- ./configure
- make

The configure output is fine. But the make fails with:

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:505: die Regel für Ziel „mtp-connect“ scheiterte
make[2]: *** [mtp-connect] Fehler 1
make[2]: Verzeichnis „/home/libmtp-1.1.12/examples“ wird verlassen
Makefile:525: die Regel für Ziel „all-recursive“ scheiterte
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Fehler 1
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/home/libmtp-1.1.12“ wird verlassen
Makefile:388: die Regel für Ziel „all“ scheiterte
make: *** [all] Fehler 2
```

in english the message could be something like this:

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:505: rule for target „mtp-connect“ failed
make[2]: *** [mtp-connect] error 1
make[2]: exit folder „/home/libmtp-1.1.12/examples“
Makefile:525: rule for target „all-recursive“ failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] error 1
make[1]: exit folder „/home/libmtp-1.1.12“
Makefile:388: rule for target „all“ failed
make: *** [all] Fehler 2
```

Anybody has an idea where to search? Where to begin?

Comment: You should begin by providing the actual error messages.  These messages are just make telling you that something failed.  The real problems are right before the lines you've quoted, before "ld returned 1 exit status"... there should be messages back there telling you why your linker (ld) failed.  We cannot possibly guess at which of the millions of reasons for this that you are facing.

Comment: ok. It is the pc of my mother. I will try to find out next week!